# htaccess non-www to www while keeping exact url

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, centos6

Im using the following in my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com [R=301,L]
```

This works except that i have urls like this `website.com/name?query=1`

The rewrite is removing the /name when typing the url with non-www

so `website.com/name?query=1` will rewrite to `www.website.com/?query=1`

Also im using Zend Framework and have the default /public folder when using

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

in the rewrite it makes the link look like this `www.website.com//public/name?query=1`

I need to not have it NOT write //public and I don't want to change the structure of the site because there are to many pointers to the /public folder

How do I get the RewriteRule to change non-www to www and not drop "name"  ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
# No W's to W's keeping all the URI items intact
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That rewrites to this http://www.website.com//public/name?itemdetails=456  I need it to not write the /public

Comment: I answered your question correctly, as you asked. If you attempt to access, say `http://www.website.com/admin/login.php&msg=error` it will redirect to `http://website.com/admin/login.php&msg=error` keeping the URL in tact. Unless you have something else going on, then I suggest adding a `RewriteBase /public/` above the rewrite conditions if everything is in `/public/`.

Comment: This is a general solution and good to discuss. The issue is that HTTP_HOST depends on the server's configuration, the ServerName in Apache, I think. It may be more reliable to use %{REQUEST_URI}

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```